# Installing libliquid-dev on a distro that doesnt support it with a repo

Tags: apt

I want to compile and install a software called [Inspectrum](https://github.com/miek/inspectrum) for which I have to fulfill a dependency "libliquid-dev" apart from other 5 dependencies listed below;

1. qt5-default
2. libfftw3-dev
3. cmake
4. pkg-config.

However, libliquid-dev was not found to be installed by apt-get even after a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 followed up by an apt-get update and an apt-get upgrade. All other dependencies were successfully found and installed via default repositories.

Hence, I started to dig deep. This is Ubuntu 16.04. I.e. **Xenial**. But, I noticed from the Ubuntu package search that libliquid-dev is not available in Xenial repos. Proof:

```
https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&keywords=libliquid-dev
```

However, I noticed that libliquid-dev is availalbe in [Artful](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=artful&keywords=libliquid-dev). 
So I went ahead and edited my /etc/apt/sources.list and added the line 
"`deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful main universe`"
This found & installed the libliquid-dev library and therefore I installed Inspectrum successfully. But in the next boot, my system completely broke down. This drives me to ask the following question.

How can I make my Ubuntu 16.04 system be able to install the library libliquid-dev without breaking its functionality?

I know so that my approach described in this question is not correct. I am searching for the most approphriate way of installing libliquid-dev in linux so that I can happily install Inspectrum while keeping operating system intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this method on my Xenial system. It does not break system, but installs 4 files out of APT control. But this method works.

1. Install build-dependencies as written in [inspectrum
   wiki](https://github.com/miek/inspectrum/wiki/Build)

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install qt5-default libfftw3-dev cmake pkg-config
   ```
2. Install `libliquid1d` and `libliquid1d-dev` from Artful manually by extracting them directly:

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/liquid-dsp/libliquid1d_1.3.0-1_amd64.deb
   dpkg -x libliquid1d_1.3.0-1_amd64.deb .

   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/liquid-dsp/libliquid-dev_1.3.0-1_amd64.deb
   dpkg -x libliquid-dev_1.3.0-1_amd64.deb .

   sudo cp  usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libliquid.* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
   sudo cp -ar usr/include/liquid /usr/include/
   ```
3. Install necessary tools for compilation

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential git
   ```
4. Clone repository and compile the program

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   git clone https://github.com/miek/inspectrum.git
   cd inspectrum
   mkdir build
   cd build
   cmake ..
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

   Note: Last step (`sudo make install`) is normal for this small project, otherwise use [checkinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware#Installing_the_Package).
5. Run installed program by `inspectrum` command.

Comment: Many thanks to your well suited answer!  However with including "deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful main universe", the apt-upgrade command triggered a large number of packages in the Xenial to be upgraded.    This update is  what broke the system.   I tested on my local mechine twice and once on a virtual mechine too.  I'm confused more when you said it worked on your mechine. DId you try including the "deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful main universe" and apt-upgrad your Xenial system?

Comment: I am so glad you are introducing me to the latest methods of finding software. Thanks for Checkinstall! Well worth using and knowing more about! Never jeard of dpkg -x . I always used dpkg -i packagename.deb 
.  Lots of new things to learn from your answer!

Comment: Many thanks for your time spent on this task and figuring this out.

Comment: Can you please explain why you opted to use dpkg -x rather than the usual dpkg -i ? Is there an advantage?

Comment: `dpkg -i` will record this installation to the database, this will cause dependency breakage and remove of installed packages on next `apt-get install -f` (if I remember correctly).